# Comparison of a function with its derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a positive-valued convex function defined on $[0,\infty)$.  Define $g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f'(x)-f(x)$.  Can an additional condition be suggested such that there exists $m \ge 0$ so that

\begin{align}
g(x) > 0 \quad &\forall x \in [0,m) \\ g(x) \le 0 \quad &\forall x \in [m,\infty).
\end{align}

I tried solving $g(x) = 0$ as an ODE, and there's infinitely many solutions.  It seems that I can't construct a curve without crossing these curves.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'd say no. Consider $f(x) = x^2+0.5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment, $f(x)=x^2+0.5$ is a counterexample, so this question is false.